# How to use pointer's pointer to print namelist?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'd like to make a member function "getList" to print a list of names.

However, I don't have any clue to use a pointer's pointer.

Any comments would be helpful for me.

```
class Happy
{
    private:
        MyString name;
        int money;
        char* list[100]; // I'd like to save a shopping list here.
        int index;

    public:
        Happy(char* np=NULL, int money=10000);
        Happy(Happy &r);
        ~Happy();
        Happy &operator=(Happy &r);

        void use(char* ip, int n);
        Happy &winner(Happy &r);
        void setName(MyString &name);
        MyString &getName();
        void setMoney(int money);
        int getMoney();
        char** getList(); // I'd like to print the shopping list with a pointer's pointer.
        int getIndex();
};
//----------------------------------------
char** Happy::getList()
{
 // How should I fill this block so that I could print lists?
}
```

Comment: If you're going the **C++** way, I'd suggest to use C++ library `std::string` instead of **C** `char` arrays to hold your character string.

Comment: And also use `std::vector` instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply `return list;`.